# Frameworks for organizing pictures - Portfolio

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frameworks

Any good frameworks out there that help in the process of posting pictures to your photography page in your portfolio website?

As of now, I'm manually adding html tags for each picture and ordering it, so every time i need to add a new one, its a lot of effort. Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a static site generator, you can just drop your images in a directory link them and work in markdown.  It makes editing blogs or personal websites much easier compared to having to get into the HTML.  I personally like Jekyll.